# Difference between `deadline_timer`and `waitable_timer` in `boost asio`

Tags: c++, boost, timer, boost-asio

To expire a timer in 5 seconds,
is there any practical difference between these two?
Is any one preferable(performance, resource, etc.) to the other for this case?

[Option 1] **`deadline_timer`**:

```
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service);
timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
```

[Option 2] **`waitable_timer`**(`system_timer` or `steady_timer`):

```
boost::asio::system_timer timer(io_service);
timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(5));
```

*PS: Please concentrate on comparing `deadline_timer` vs. `system_timer`, rather than `system_timer` vs. `steady_timer`.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only difference is between clock types used.

As of Boost 1.56, both `basic_deadline_timer` and `basic_waitable_timer` use `detail::deadline_timer_service` inside.

There's no difference in how it performs waiting, the only difference is in how it performs time calculation.

In its `wait()` method it uses `Time_Traits::now()` to check if it needs to wait more. For `system_timer` it's `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`, and for `deadline_timer` it's `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()` or `boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time()` depending on the presence of high precision clock (see [time_traits.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/asio/time_traits.hpp)).

`std::chrono::system_clock` implementation is provided by a compiler/standard library vendor, whereas `boost::posix_time::*clock` is implemented by Boost using available system functions.

These implementations of course may have different performance and/or precision depending on the platform and the compiler.

Answer (score 6):

There is excellent responce to similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16364002/3491378

Basically, the main difference is that if you expect any external changes to the system clock, you should rather use steady_timer - deadline_timer delay will be affected by those changes

Comment: To clarify your answer, do you mean there would be no practical difference in the case that the system clock will not be modified?

Comment: If I get you right - yes. If the system clock is not modified during the delay you set (5 seconds in the example), the practical difference would be negligible (as Anton said - the only difference will be in their implementations)